# Raw "Insert" SQL in SQLAlchemy, Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Values are not added to the database after INSERT query. SELECT is working fine this way

```
  db = SQLAlchemy(app)
  ...
  session['sql_raw_reports_post'] = "insert into database (x, y) values (xa, ya)"
  r = db.session.execute(session['sql_raw_reports_post'])
  ...
  return 'success'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try add

```
db.commit()
```

ater "insert" action